# For a finite reversible irreducible Markov chain with transition matrix $P$, why is $P(x,y)>0$ equivalent to $P(y,x)>0$?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $P$ be the transition matrix for a reversible irreducible finite Markov chain with respect to the stationary measure $\pi$.

How can I prove $P(x,y)>0$ iff $P(y,x)>0$?

What I know is that by defintion of reversibility,

$$\pi(x)P(x,y)=\pi(y)P(y,x)$$.

I tried to show the equivalence $P(x,y)=0$ iff $P(y,x)=0$, which makes it sufficient to show $P(x,y)=0$ with $\pi(y)=0$ is impossible.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think this is not true with the stated assumptions. Consider the chain on $\{x,y\}$ where $p(x,x) = p(x,y) = 0.5$ and $p(y,y)= 1$. The stationary distribution is $\pi(x) = 0$ and $\pi(x) = 1$. Is it possible the chain should also be assumed to be irreducible?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Yes, irreducibility is assumed I will correct the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint, in the form of a possible strategy for how you might approach this:

1. If no state $x$ has $\pi(x) = 0$, then the result is obvious.
2. If one state $x$ has $\pi(x) = 0$, show that this is infectious; that is, any state $y$ with $p(y,x) > 0$ must have $\pi(y) = 0$ as well. Use this, and irreducibility, to argue that there is some pair of states $a$ and $b$ such that $\pi(a) = 0$, $\pi(b) \neq 0$, and $\pi(b, a) > 0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Irreducibility shows that $\pi$ must be identically zero for your second case which is a contradiction, so we are done. Thanks.